# Puppet: audit on external file changes?

Tags: puppet, audit

In my puppet managed environment, one service needs to be restarted each time a file changes. The file itself is not under puppet's control but part of a package, i.e., may gets updated during (yum) updates.

Thus, I would like to 'subscribe' to this file and trigger a service restart on changes.

Since the file is not managed by Puppet, some audit-like approach does not work

```
file { '/path/to/foo':
  audit => content,
}

notify { 'foo.notify':
  subscribe => File['/path/to/foo'],
  message  => "foo has changed"
}
```

Is there a way, to realize something like that in Puppet?
Ideally, I would only need to compare on the client the current vs the previous file hash.

But AFAIS within Puppet's structure, it would require to keep the current file hash on the puppet master and compare it again on the client (which may work via a fact but would be clumsy(?)).

Comment: If Puppet is controlling the package then subscribe to the package.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem to work with Puppet `4.4.2` and `3.4.3`, so it's safe to assume that both Puppet `3.x` and `4.x` do the right thing here:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo foo >foo
$ puppet apply -e 'file { "/tmp/foo": audit => "content" } ~> exec { "/bin/echo DING": refreshonly => true }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for this-box in environment production in 0.13 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/foo]/content: audit change: newly-recorded value {md5}d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.07 seconds
$ puppet apply -e 'file { "/tmp/foo": audit => "content" } ~> exec { "/bin/echo DING": refreshonly => true }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for this-box in environment production in 0.12 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.06 seconds
$ echo bar >foo
$ puppet apply -e 'file { "/tmp/foo": audit => "content" } ~> exec { "/bin/echo DING": refreshonly => true }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for this-box in environment production in 0.12 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/foo]/content: audit change: previously recorded value {md5}d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00 has been changed to {md5}c157a79031e1c40f85931829bc5fc552
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[/bin/echo DING]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.09 seconds
```

Please note that `notify` does not work very well with events. Putting the `subscribe` in an actual service resource should work much better and lead to a service restart.

Comment: "It does seem to work with Puppet `4.4.2`" meaning this works in Puppet `>= 4.4.2` and not before?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I lazily did not test any other versions. I suppose it will work with any `4.x` and I believe so for `3.x`. Will run a little `3.4.3` test and update the answer.

Comment: Ok, it just seemed an interesting version to pick. 4.8.1 is the latest, 4.7.0 is the latest inside a PE, and 4.6.2 is what I consider latest stable, so I was curious why the choice of 4.4.2.

Comment: That's probably what was installed at $work and was the easiest to test with... unless it was the most up to date version in $distro's package repo.

Comment: Actually, that was `master` at the time I had created the git clone from which I tested ;p